# Excel formula to write a word in the same cell after I write an specific word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new in excel and I'm doing a project. I'm wondering if its possible to write a word in a cell and straight away the formula writes another word in parenthesis besides the word I did write before. For example I add a picture of more or less what I'm looking for. Thank you for your help!
[Excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peWxT.png)

Comment: You would need to use VBA if you want the same cell to be updated. If there is a finite number of potential entries, you may want to look at Data validation

Comment: You could achieve this in the cell next to the one you enter the text in though with a reference table and VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH

Comment: Thank you for your answer Richard, do you know an specific formula I can use for it? something simple maybe, I don't want something too complicated for this. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried autocorrect?

Comment: Can you be more specific Mike? can I set up the autocorrect in excel so when I write a word it writes another word next to it in the same cell?

Comment: @David have you tried what I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the autocorrect facility for this, see :
[image]

I typed "tres" in cell B2 and it was replaced as expected.

Comment: That's brilliant!  Unintended feature posts like this are one of the reasons I love SO.